# How to get graph value from Zabbix API

Tags: api, monitoring, zabbix

I just try to using zabbix API. I following step by step from https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api

i trying to using get method to get value from graph like bellow :

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "graph.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend",
        "sortfield": "name",
         "hostid": "10084"
    },
    "auth": "50ba559f6d083aa6454b8b3c4c203baa",
    "id": 1
}
```

Then i get value like bellow :

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        ...

        {
            "graphid": "481",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "463",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "457",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "495",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "469",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "433",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "524",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "433",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "534",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "495",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "475",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        },
        {
            "graphid": "487",
            "name": "CPU load",
            "width": "900",
            "height": "200",
            "yaxismin": "0.0000",
            "yaxismax": "100.0000",
            "templateid": "0",
            "show_work_period": "1",
            "show_triggers": "1",
            "graphtype": "0",
            "show_legend": "1",
            "show_3d": "0",
            "percent_left": "0.0000",
            "percent_right": "0.0000",
            "ymin_type": "1",
            "ymax_type": "0",
            "ymin_itemid": "0",
            "ymax_itemid": "0",
            "flags": "0"
        }

       ...

    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

From that output i can't get any value which like on graph which show on Zabbix Dashboard Graph.i also don't get any value on any graph which show on json output.

How i can get value CPU Load like :

```
processor load (1 min average per core) [avg]  last:0.23 min:0.02 avg:017 max:0.74

processor load (5 min average per core) [avg]  last:0.17 min:0.02 avg:017 max:0.4

etc
```

Anyone could help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

You mix up the monitoring data and monitoring configuration. "graph.get" gets you the configuration of the graph, not the graph itself and not the values. You need to [get history](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference/history/get) of items to see the values.